# How can I get and change the Value of the "(Standard)" key in the Registry with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I need to write a Script to change the Value of the (Standard) Key located in the Registry under:

```
REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
```

I just cant get anything to work, everything i tried gives me the same response.

The Closest i've been is probably the following Code (was searching for a Solution Online):

```bash
$keypath = 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command\'
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $keypath -Name '(Standard)').'(Standard)'
```

But all I get back from it is:

```
Property (Standard) does not exist at path HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command.
```

even though it clearly does exists. I assume im doing something clearly wrong, I tried searching for a solution and all I found was the code above.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas the **.NET APIs** represent the unnamed default value as the ***empty string*** (`''` or `""` in PowerShell), **PowerShell's [registry provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Registry_Provider)** uses **`'(default)'`** (*invariably*; that is, this **string is *not* localized** according the Windows display language, whereas it *is* in Registry Editor, for instance):

```
$keypath = 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command\'

# GET the data of the unnamed default value.
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $keypath -Name '(default)'

# SET the data of the unnamed default value - REQUIRES ELEVATION
Set-ItemProperty -Path $keypath -Name '(default)' -Value 'new value'
```

Note:

- [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) rather than [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) is used in order to directly extract only the *data* from the targeted registry value.
- *Modifying* data in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registry hive usually requires *elevation* (running as admin).
- Use of **.NET APIs as an alternative**:

  - For *getting* the data, you could alternatively use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) and call the [`.GetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue) method on the resulting [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) instance as follows:

    ```
    # GET the data of the unnamed default value.
    # EQUIVALENT OF:
    #    Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $keypath -Name '(default)'
    (Get-Item $keypath).GetValue('')
    ```
  - However, for *setting* the data, using the complementary [`.SetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue) method does NOT work, because the `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` instance returned by `Get-Item` is *read-only*. Therefore, use of `.SetValue()` requires use of .NET APIs *only*:

    ```
    # SET the data of the unnamed default value - REQUIRES ELEVATION
    # NOTE:
    #  * Do NOT use a leading '\' in the key path.
    #  * $true as the second argument makes the key writeable.
    $regKey = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
      'http\shell\open\command', 
       $true
    ) 
    $regKey.SetValue('', 'new value')
    $regKey.Dispose()
    ```

Comment: hey mklement0, tysm for your answer. With your Code i had no Problem getting the correct and wanted Output. Seems like I was just dumb, I've discovered that the Problem probably was that i wrote '(Standard)' instead of '(default)'. Even tho my German installed windows Server shows me Standard, powershell ofc. expects default. 

Have a great day @mklemen0 and thank you again for your Help!

Comment: @Lextor, glad to hear it helped; my pleasure. Good point that one might expect the string to be _localized_ - I've updated the answer to make it clear that it is not.